# How to use Get Data in Excel without loading the data fully in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, powerpivot

I have a minor nuisance regarding loading the data into Excel. I load data from a SQL database as follows: first go to the tab **Data** > Get Data > From Database > From SQL Server Database. However, if I select a table for example: employees, Excel will try to download the entire table into my Excel. This makes my Excel prohibitively large and not workable.

However, when I have loaded everything into PowerBI （online） and then try to connect Excel to it, it leaves the data in PowerBI and then I can use pivots to get aggregated views from the data.

I suspect this is due to the use of "From Analysis Services", but I am not entirely sure. I am wondering how can I make the Excel Power Pivots talk to the SQL database and make the appropriate aggregations without loading the entire dataset into Excel?

Am I forced to use "From Analysis Services" or are there also other （preferably open source） solutions in which this also work?

[image: SQL database load option in Excel]

Comment: Have you tried getting data as a query so you can pull just the data you want instead of the entire table? Would that even work for your use case? At the very least,  you could limit the fields you're including.

Comment: It's not about necessarily pulling a subset of the dataset. I have good SQL knowledge, however I cannot say that about the users. From my understanding, they prefer to aggregate the data at certain levels themselves in a pivot table. I would like to have the aggregation step done by the database, just like what is possible with PowerBI, but not necessarily use PowerBI.

Comment: I think I have seen an option in excel power query to not save or download the whole dataset from the source. I have not used SQL as a data source, so I unfortunately cant offer a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at loading options here

https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query-tips-and-tricks/

I think what you arw looking fornis load to data model and not load to table.

Comment: Dear Mobus, that's not correct. I do not even want to load it into the data model. I just want the pivot to "translate" the query into SQL or something that the database can understand. Database does the calculations and then spit the results back to the Excel and then the Excel just updates the pivot. I know this can be done with an Analysis Service, but there should be alternatives imho.

Comment: Can you not define the connection as "connection only" and then use "Load to:"?